# How to set mysql default Time zone when server restart?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, server

I am using AWS linux instance.

How can i set default time zone '+05:30'?

I tired editing my.cnf file and added

> default-time-zone='+05:30'

but it doesn't effect.

I also tried to set through command like

> set global time-zone = '+05:30'

and it was working but when i restart the server it set to default time zone "SYSTEM" (00:00).

Can anyone help?

Comment: How do you start you sql when your server restarts ? Do you stat with command line / service ?

Comment: Verify that you have added this to the `[mysqld]` section of my.cnf and restart the server.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yes it is in [mysqld] section.

Comment: @Kannaiyan when i do "sevice mysql restart" or when server restarts automatic, its get override by default time

Comment: Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
/usr/etc/my.cnf
~/.my.cnf

Comment: Do you want to check whether timezone is overridden in any other files?

Comment: @Kannaiyan Yes!

Comment: Did that fix or you are still having problem ?

Comment: I am still having the problem

Comment: @Kannaiyan i am getting this weird error too, please look at this and answer if you know the issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377468/what-is-wrong-in-my-store-procedure-syntax)