# What is wrong in my stored procedure syntax?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1064

I am getting this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server  version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

I am using stored procedure to retrieve data and in this I am using pagination

Here is my stored procedure code :

```
  CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `usp_get_product_wall_details`(
    IN `in_user_id` INT,
    IN `in_product_name` VARCHAR(50),
    IN `in_category_id` INT

,
    IN `in_order_by` VARCHAR(50),
    IN `in_order_type` VARCHAR(50),
    IN `in_page_no` INT,
    IN `in_limit` INT



)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER

BEGIN


DECLARE var_offset INT;
DECLARE var_limit INT DEFAULT 10;


IF in_limit != 0 THEN
    set var_limit = in_limit;
END IF;

set var_offset = (in_page_no - 1) * var_limit;
set @sql = '';
set @query = '';

    set @query= concat("select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS p.id,p.product_name,p.seller_count,p.rating,p.rating_count,pii.image_url,
    padem.product_mrp,padem.minimum_selling_price,max(padem.discount_price) as discount_price,
    max(padem.discount_percentage) as discount_percentage,pade.enum_value,padem.id as enum_id 
    from product p
    inner join abc padem on padem.product_id = p.id
    INNER JOIN cd pii ON padem.product_id = pii.product_id
    inner join ef pade on pade.id = padem.attribute_dropdown_enum_id
    where p.`status` = 1 and pii.is_thumbnail = 1 and padem.seller_id is not null and
    pii.enum_mapping_id = (select pad.id from product_attribute_dropdown_enum_mapping pad where pad.product_id = padem.product_id and
    pad.attribute_dropdown_enum_id = padem.attribute_dropdown_enum_id and pad.seller_id is null) and
    padem.sort_order = (select min(sort_order) from product_attribute_dropdown_enum_mapping where product_id = padem.product_id group by product_id) 
    and (p.product_name like concat('tropicana','%') or p.product_name like concat('%','tropicana','%')) 
    group by p.id
    order by ",in_order_by," ",in_order_type," limit ", var_offset,",",var_limit);

set @sql = concat(@sql,@query);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

When I execute this procedure I am getting the error.

But at the same time if I run simple query outside the stored procedure with some static data, I can retrieve the data perfectly.

Table names were changed

Comment: Can you show us the entire procedure definition (starting with `CREATE PROCEDURE`) and how you are calling it?

Comment: @Nick i have updated the code

Comment: What does your `CALL usp_get_product_wall_details` statement look like?

Comment: @Nick CALL `usp_get_product_wall_details`('0', 'tropicana', 0, 'price', 'desc', '1', '10')

Comment: *@DhruvPatadia*: check the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/23160180/767881 helps you

Comment: @RavinderReddy i am not getting error in creating procedure and i have indeed set the delimiter.

Comment: Although I don't have your exact tables, I can't replicate your problem. When I execute the procedure it runs fine.

Comment: @Nick can it be problem of SQL mode or like anything like that?

Comment: I struggle to see where `NULL` is coming from. The only thing I note is that your parameters are type `INT` but some of them you are passing strings to e.g. `in_page_no` you are passing `'1'` instead of `1`. With a strict SQL mode that might cause problems with `var_offset` generation. What happens if you `CALL usp_get_product_wall_details('0', 'tropicana', 0, 'price', 'desc', 1, 10)`?

Comment: @Nick same issue

Comment: @Nick i tracked that the issue is when i pass the input parameter to product name in like query it gives me error but when i directly pass the name like i did in code it run perfect, so can you suggest the solution

Comment: @DhruvPatadia the code you posted doesn't use `in_product_name` so, no. If you post the *actual* code you are running it might be possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution by restarting MySQL server:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```